# Copying Excel values based on another value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet with a list of zip-codes and I need values from another workbook to be placed next to the zip codes based on the matching zip-code for each value. I do not know how to write macros and was wondering if someone could post the basic code for me so that I could add the correct cells and values as needed into the code. (please let me know where to add it in).

Here is a sample of what I mean:

```
zip code column list
11004
11005
11101
11102
11103
11104
11105
11106
11109
11120
11351
11352
11354
11355
11356
11357
```

zip code and value from other workbook

```
11693   151
```

For example, if the zip-code 11693 exists in the list of zip codes, I would want the value 151 placed in the cell next to it.

Comment: seems like you could use vlookup rather than vba. Use text to columns to break things like 11693 151 into two columns (if not in two columns already) and treat the resulting two columns as a lookup array

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! We are happy to help you if you are stuck, but we can't write a whole code for you. You must show some effort yourself here. That said, you don't need a macro, all you need is a VLOOKUP function. See [here](http://www.trackpal.co.uk/blog/vlookup-for-beginners/) for some more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can use VLOOKUP, try this..

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$5,1,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE))
```

Use above formula on Sheet1 : Column B

Here:

- Sheet1 contains the Zipcode List *(result 3 digits gets added to this sheet on Column B)*

[image]

- Sheet2 contains the Zipcode with 3 digit code next to it.

[image]

Comment: Some of my values are not being pasted for some reason, is there something else I need to do? thanks

Comment: Can you double check the Range used in VLOOKUP formula..- you should have it for all available rows in Sheet2. in above example i mentioned `Sheet2!$A$1:$B$5` as data is there only from A1 to B5 in Sheet2

Comment: You were right-I fixed the range and it worked. Thank you